# Rolagem horizontal utilizando Swipe, Touch ou Drag

Tags: javascript, html, rolamento

Possuo 4 *tables* de informação, e gostaria de fazer um *swipeleft* ou *right*, o mesmo a fim de mudar para a próxima tabela ou anterior.

Exemplo:

http://prntscr.com/8vvc2j

Meu código HTML e CSS atual:

http://jsfiddle.net/pedropcruz/twnhLL4j/

Explicação do *fiddle*:

- ele mostra 4, 3, 2 e 1 tabela conforme a resolução.
- Para mobile já está resolvido, utilizando o *click* conforme o comprimento de cada tabela é realizado a troca para o seguinte.
- O class="col-xs-1" presente, é o horário, que não tem *swipe*, ou seja, tem de manter sempre no mesmo sitio.

Para  *desktop*, **gostaria que ao arrastar mostra-se o mesmo mais ao lado esquerdo ou direito utilizando o evento *touch*, *drag* ou *swipe*** (OBS.: não conheço a diferença entre esses eventos).

Comment: Obrigado @Rafael Kendrik pela edição , eu não sou brazileiro daí não me saber explicar tão bem.